Suma personalizada
playerCards es una lista de tipo string que contiene solamente valores pertenecientes al diccionario EnvidoRanks. Lo que intento hacer es sumar todos los valores de playerCards que empiecen con M a Suma, este es el diccionario y lo que intente por ahora (Me dice como error: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'string'):
private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> EnvidoRanks = new()
{
    { "M2", 10 },
    { "M4", 9 },
    { "M5", 8 },
    { "MQ", 7 }, { "O7", 7 }, { "C7", 7 }, { "E7", 7 }, { "B7", 7 },
    { "MJ", 6 }, { "O6", 6 }, { "C6", 6 }, { "E6", 6 }, { "B6", 6 },
    { "O5", 5 }, { "C5", 5 }, { "E5", 5 }, { "B5", 5 },
    { "O4", 4 }, { "C4", 4 }, { "E4", 4 }, { "B4", 4 },
    { "O3", 3 }, { "C3", 3 }, { "E3", 3 }, { "B3", 3 },
    { "O2", 2 }, { "C2", 2 }, { "E2", 2 }, { "B2", 2 },
    { "O1", 1 }, { "C1", 1 }, { "E1", 1 }, { "B1", 1 },
    { "OK", 0 }, { "CK", 0 }, { "EK", 0 }, { "BK", 0 }, { "OQ", 0 }, { "CQ", 0 }, { "EQ", 0 }, { "BQ", 0 }, { "OJ", 0 }, { "CJ", 0 }, { "EJ", 0 }, { "BJ", 0 },
};

int Suma = playerCards.Select(p => p[0] == 'M').Select(a => EnvidoRanks[a]).Sum();


Vayamos paso a paso:
var llaves = EnvidoRanks.Keys.Where(k => k[0] == 'M').ToList();
var lista = playerCards.Where(p => p[0] == 'M');
var interseccion = llaves.Intersect(lista).ToDictionary(k => k, EnvidoRanks[k]);
var suma = interseccion.Values.Sum();

Del diccionario EnvidoRanks se seleccionan todas las llaves cuyo primer carácter sea 'M'.
De la lista playerCards se seleccionan todos los elementos cuyo primer carácter sea 'M'.
Posteriormente se hace una intersección para obtener los elementos en común y a partir de esta intersección se crea un nuevo diccionario donde la llave es el resultado obtenido de la intersección y el valor será el valor que tiene EnvidoRanks a partir de la nueva llave.
Finalmente se hace una suma de los valores del nuevo diccionario.
